# spin redis from docker-it-scala

Tags: scala, docker, redis, sbt

I am trying to spin a docker container from [docker-it-scala](https://github.com/whisklabs/docker-it-scala).
The goal is to be able to run unit tests against the redis in the container as opposed to prod which is a managed service (AWS ElastiCache)

I build a Service, following quite closely the

```
import com.spotify.docker.client.{DefaultDockerClient, DockerClient}
import com.whisk.docker.impl.spotify.SpotifyDockerFactory
import com.whisk.docker.{DockerContainer, DockerFactory, DockerKit, DockerReadyChecker}

// Look at https://github.com/whisklabs/docker-it-scala
// .. and let yourself be inspired
trait DockerRedisService extends DockerKit {

  val redisDefaultPort = 6379

  val redisContainer = DockerContainer("redis")
    .withPorts(redisDefaultPort -> None)
    .withReadyChecker(DockerReadyChecker.LogLineContains("Ready to accept connections"))

  abstract override def dockerContainers: List[DockerContainer] =
    redisContainer :: super.dockerContainers

}
```

From there, I should be able to run some unit tests

```
class ElastiCache extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter with ScalaFutures with DockerRedisService {

  private val client: DockerClient = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build()
  override implicit val dockerFactory: DockerFactory = new SpotifyDockerFactory(client)

  implicit val pc = PatienceConfig(Span(40, Seconds), Span(1, Second))

  "the redis container" should "be ready with log line checker" in {
    isContainerReady(redisContainer).futureValue shouldBe true
    redisContainer.getPorts().futureValue.get(6379 ) should not be empty
    redisContainer.getIpAddresses().futureValue should not be Seq.empty
  }
```

The unit test just times out without too much information.

It would be useful to see how I could hset and hget some values out of that redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing execution trait specifying java-docker backend.

Your `class ElastiCache` should extend one or the other:

#### Using `docker-testkit-impl-docker-java`

```
with DockerTestKit with DockerKitDockerJava
```

#### Using `docker-testkit-impl-spotify`

```
with DockerTestKit with DockerKitDockerSpotify
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create the docker client or setup the docker factory. You just need to add all the appropriate traits which do that for you.

```
 class ElastiCache extends FlatSpec with Matchers 
    with DockerTestKit with DockerRedisService with DockerKitDockerJava
```

Also, if your tests are running on the host and they need access to those containers, you probably need to expose the port:

```
    .withPorts(6379 -> Some(9999))
```

That will map the default Redis port `6379` in the container to the host port `9999`.